# Php y sql query

Tags: php, sql, odbc

Tengo un problema con una consulta sql con php, necesito calcular el total de unidades vendidas por vendedor, estoy limitando el numero de registros a mostrar porque la base de datos tiene cientos de registros, y apenas estoy probando la consulta.

Pero al realizar la consulta me salen estos dos errores:

> Warning: odbc_exec (): SQL error: [TOD] [ODBC] [GENESIS] Non aggregates require a GROUP BY expression.
>
> Warning: odbc_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Este es mi código:

```
 <?php 
  $sqlVend = "SELECT TOP 10 VEN_LLAVE, VEN_NOMBRE, SUM(VDOC_UDS) AS Suma, 
              from VENVEN, VENDOC 
              where VENVEN.VEN_LLAVE = VENDOC.VDOC_VEND GROUP BY VEN_LLAVE, VEN_NOMBRE";
  $resVend = odbc_exec($cone, $sqlVend);
  while (odbc_fetch_row($resVend)) {
    # code...
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo odbc_result($resVend, 'VEN_LLAVE') ?></td>
  <td><?php echo odbc_result($resVend, 'VEN_NOMBRE') ?></td>
  <td><?php echo odbc_result($resVend, 'Suma') ?></td>

</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Creo que falta agrupar por VDOC_UDS también.

Comment: @Shaz, Hola Shaz primero que nada gracias por responder, al principio tambien agrupaba VDOC_UDS en la funcion de group by pero me sale el mismo error, supongo que no necesito agrupar ese campo porque lo estoy usando en la funcion de agregacion sum(). Tienes alguna otra sugerencia? De antemano gracias.

Comment: Es verdad, no me había fijado en esa parte.

Comment: Necesitas algún otro dato para orientarme en este problema @Shaz?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Groupby

El problema es que tienes VDOC_UDS en el `select` pero no en la cláusula de agregación.

Le dices que agrupe por VEN_LLAVE y VEN_NOMBRE, y en el la selección tienes esas columnas y la suma de las unidades, hasta ahí todo correcto. También le pides las unidades, pero las unidades correspondientes a qué?  Por cada par (VEN_LLAVE, VEN_NOMBRE) puede haber varios valores de VDOC_UDS y la base de datos no sabe cual darte.

Un ejemplo sencillo:

```
+----------+------------+-------+ 
|VEN_LLAVE | VEN_NOMBRE |VEN_UDS|
+----------+------------+-------+ 
|    1     |   Luis     |   4   |
+----------+------------+-------+ 
|    1     |   Luis     |   12  |
+----------+------------+-------+ 
|     1    |   Luis     |   1   |
+----------+------------+-------+ 
|     2    |  Marcos    |   7   |
+----------+------------+-------+
|     2    |  Marcos    |   3   |
+----------+------------+-------+ 
|     2    |    Juan    |   13  |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

Con tu query si no te devolviera error, el resultado sería:

```
+----------+------------+-------+------------+ 
|VEN_LLAVE | VEN_NOMBRE |VEN_UDS|sum(VEN_UDS)|
+----------+------------+-------+------------+
|    1     |    Luis    |   ??  |     17     |
+----------+------------+-------+------------+
|    2     |    Marcos  |   ??  |     10     | 
+----------+------------+-------+------------+
|    2     |    Juan    |   13  |     13     |
+----------+------------+-------+------------+
```

Como ves para los dos primeras filas la columna VEN_UDS no tiene sentido, deberías quitarla de la consulta.

### Top

Aqui me parece que tienes una idea equivocada de como funciona `top`, esta función lo que limita es el número de filas que la base de datos **devuelve** despues de haber hecho todos los cálculos apropiados, así que si la tabla es grande esta condición no va a hacer la consulta más rápida.

Si quieres limitar el numero de filas a las que se aplica el `sum` tienes que hacerlo a traves de la clausula `where` limitando la consulta a unos ids o unos días determinados por ejemplo.

Comment: El resultado de tener VEN_UDS en la lista de columnas y en la cláusula de agregación, no es el mismo que si no lo está. Tendrá sentido (o no) dependiendo de qué es lo que quiera hacer OP

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tenerlo en la clausula de agregación cambiará lo que se devuelve y no creo que sea lo que OP quiere, tenerlo en el select es lo creo que le da el error.

Comment: Hola buen dia!, perimero que nada muchas gracias por responder, VDOC_UDS es el nombre del campo que almacena las unidades vendidas por cada vendedor, lo que intento hacer es que me de la suma de las unidades vendidas por vendedor, justamente como lo señalas en la segunda tabla de tu ejemplo @DansMerino, con la diferencia de que solo quiero jalar el top 10 de vendedores. De nuevo les agradezco el tiempo que se tomaron en orientarme, modificare el select como mencionas y veré que sucede.

Comment: Ya hice las modificaciones correspondientes, al parecer eso soluciona los dos errores que me mostraba, solo que se queda cargando la consulta y no llega a mostrarme los datos (aún). Creo que es porque la funcion SUM(VDOC_UDS) esta realizando la suma de todos los registros de la tabla y son muchísimos registros. Al yo limitar la consulta con el SELECT TOP 10 supuse que solo sumaria esos 10 registros. Alguna idea? De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: @Byte He modificado la respuesta y te he respondido a esto último :)